# Creating new Services in service fabric will cause duplicated code

Tags: azure-service-fabric, etw

The visual studio project templates for a Service fabric services contains code that can be reused over other multiple projects. For example the ServiceEventSource.cs or ActorEventSource.cs

My programmer instinct wants to move this code to a shared library, so I don't have duplicate code. But maybe this isn't the way to go with microservices, since you want to have small independent services. Introducing a library will make it more dependent. But they are already dependent on the EventSource class.

My solution will be to move some reusable code to a base class in a shared project and inherit that class in my services. Is this the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved a lot of duplicate code to my own nuget libraries which is working quiet well. It is a extra dependency, but always better then duplicate code. Now I'm planning to make my one SF templates in visual studio, so I don't have to remove and adjust some files.

I found a nice library (EventSourceProxy) which helps me managing the EventSource code for ETW: https://github.com/jonwagner/EventSourceProxy

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing all your services are going to be doing lots of different jobs so once you pad out your EventSource classes they'll be completely different from each other except one method which would be service started?

Like with any logging there is many different approaches, one of the main ones I like is using AOP or interceptor proxies using IoC containers, this will keeps your classes clean but allows re-use of the ETW code and a decent amount of logging to be able to debug later down the line.